# Ceiling Fan wiring and install

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan, junction-box

3 main questions. I am trying to replace a light fixture with a ceiling fan/light combo. I've read that some boxes are not rated for ceiling fans.

1. How do I find out and/or can you tell from my pic?
2. The fan bracket would not fit my box, so I picked up a universal one. Is it installed correctly?
3. Wiring. 2 whites together, 1 brown and 1 yellow (not used with previous fixture). How am I to connect the black, blue, white, green? I saw something about grounding occurring through metal conduit and I "think" that may be what I have, but still don't know what it means for the install.

Comment: If you can't imbed your pic because you are new to the site, simply place it on Imgur and post the link to it as a comment here. We will then attach the pic to your question. Welcome to Home Improvement SE.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/21082/how-to-tell-if-a-ceiling-junction-box-is-braced-to-hold-the-weight-of-a-ceiling

Comment: Can you try [edit]ing your post, then using the "mountain and sun" icon on the editor toolbar to add your picture?